# connect() function stopping program

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I am writing two programs (client and server) that are supposed to connect to one another. I have finally gotten all the individual bugs worked out, but when I got to test the  client program (after starting and server), the connect function stops the progress of the code. I tested this with some simple text outputs.

Here is my server code (not really important)

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{



    WSAData WinSockData;
    WORD DLLVERSION;
    DLLVERSION = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    int wsa_success = WSAStartup(DLLVERSION, &WinSockData);
    if (wsa_success != 0)
    {   
        printf("Error %d while starting WSA\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 1;
    }



    SOCKET uc_socket;
    uc_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (uc_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Error %d while creating socket\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 1;
    }



    SOCKADDR_IN ADDRESS;
    int AddressSize = sizeof(ADDRESS);



    ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    ADDRESS.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ADDRESS.sin_port = htons(444);



    int bind_success = bind(uc_socket, (SOCKADDR *)&ADDRESS, AddressSize);
    if (bind_success != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d while binding socket\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 1;
    }



    int listen_success = listen(uc_socket, 12);
    if (listen_success != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d while setting socket to listen\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 1;
    }


    SOCKET c_socket;
    SOCKADDR_IN client_sock;
    int client_sock_size = sizeof(client_sock);
    printf("Socket created; Set to listen for incoming connections\n");
    c_socket = accept(uc_socket, (SOCKADDR *)&client_sock, &client_sock_size);
    if (c_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Error %d while accepting connection request\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Connection established!");
    }

    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

And my client code

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int wsasuccessful = -1;
    WSAData WinSockData;
    WORD DLLVERSION;
    DLLVERSION = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    wsasuccessful = WSAStartup(DLLVERSION, &WinSockData);
    if (wsasuccessful != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d in client while starting WSA\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 1;
    }



    SOCKET client_socket;
    client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (WSAGetLastError() != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d in client while instantiating socket\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 1;
    }



    SOCKADDR_IN client_connection;
    client_connection.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client_connection.sin_port = htons(444);
    client_connection.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_LOOPBACK;


    int connection_success = -1;
    printf("before connect()\n");  //for debugging
    connection_success = connect(client_socket, (SOCKADDR *)&client_connection, sizeof(client_connection));
    printf("after conenct()\n");  //for debugging
    if (connection_success != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d in client while instantiating socket\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 2;
    }
    printf("The client has found a server!");
    printf("The last WSA error was: %d", WSAGetLastError());


    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

Both of the programs run without issue, but they don't connect to one another. I have configured my system to allow the listening and connecting.

The server output is - 
*Socket created; Set to listen for incoming connections*

The client output is - *before connect()*

The issue as I see it is that the client isn't recognizing the listening socket on port 444 and is holding up the program until the connection can be made.

I could bypass this with a nonblocking socket, but that wouldn't solve the underlying issue.

**EDIT: forgot to include my stdafx.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <Inaddr.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <Windef.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <WinNT.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void pause(void);  //defined in stdafx.cpp
```

Same for both server and client

**EDIT 2: Finally received WSA error 10060 after changing SOCKADDR to SOCKADDR_IN in the accept() function in the server code.**

The problem still remains, but now at least I know that it's the connection failing, and not the code.

Comment: No one has your stdafx.h

Comment: The server code is passing a `sockaddr` instead of a `sockaddr_in` to `accept()`. And your client code is misusing `WSAGetLastError()` on the `socket()` call.  And some of your `printf()` calls on both sides are missing `\n` characters so the output might not be getting flushed to the console.

Comment: The params of the accept() function ask for a sockaddr according to the MSDN docs. If I remember correctly, they can be interchanged, but why are the docs asking for sockaddr rather than sockaddr_in?

Comment: `accept()` is an **old** function.  At the time it was created, `sockaddr` was the only socket address struct available.  Other the years, additional address types have been created, but the signature of `accept()` is locked in and cannot change. That is why it still takes a `sockaddr*` parameter, but the `addrlen` parameter specifies the actual size of the structure and it fills the structure data accordingly. The same goes for `connect()`, where the first field of the structure indicates the actual address type being passed in, and the `namelen` specifies the actual structure size.

Comment: Winsock error 10060 is `WSAETIMEDOUT`. You can't get that error from `accept()`.  Please show your latest code, you are still doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

connect is a blocking operation (by default). It is trying to connect and wont return until it works or fails. Sounds like it is going to time out , probably due to ports being blocked by windows firewall on the server machine. How long have you waited? Does it ever complete (with a failure)

Comment: You really shouldn't be asking questions in an answer. This would have been better suited as a comment instead. Otherwise, it should be re-worded to state facts instead of solicit more input.

Comment: I have waited for a few minutes before and the system hasn't finished. It has never completed, nor has it even acknowledged that the other program was running.

Comment: did u disable windows firewall on the server machine

Comment: I am running both client and server on the same system, using INADDR_LOOPBACK (127.0.0.1) for the client connect address

Comment: If the firewall were blocking the connection, even a local connection, connect() would fail eventually when the socket times out internally, certainly within a couple of minutes at most, more likely within a few seconds. The only way to specify a custom timeout is to put the socket in non-blocking mode before calling `connect()` and then use `select()` to detect when the connection is complete or times out.